# Random Choice with different distributions for each sample

Tags: python, numpy, random, probability, distribution

Imagine we want to randomly get `n` times **0** or **1**. But every time we make a random choice we want to give a different probability distribution.

Considering [np.random.choice](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html):

```
a = [0, 1] or just 2
size = n
p = [
        [0.2, 0.8],
        [0.5, 0.5],
        [0.7, 0.3]
] # For instance if n = 3
```

The problem is that p needs to be a 1-dimensional vector. How can we make something like this without having to call [np.random.choice](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) `n` different times?

The reason why I need to do this without calling [np.random.choice](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) multiple times is that I want an output of size `n` using a seed for reproducibility. However if I call [np.random.choice](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) `n` times with a seed the randomness is lost within the `n` calls.

What I need is the following:

```
s = sample(a, n, p) # len(a) = len(p)
print(s)
>>> [1, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Probably just a typo, but I think the first row of `p` should sum to 1.  Did you mean something like `[0.2, 0.8]`?

Answer (score 3):

Numpy has a way to get an array of random floats, between 0 and 1, like so:

```
>>> a = np.random.uniform(0, 1, size=3)
>>> a
array([0.41444637, 0.90898856, 0.85223613])
```

Then, you can compare those floats with the probabilities you want:

```
>>> p = np.array([0.01, 0.5, 1])
>>> (a < p).astype(int)
array([0, 0, 1])
```

(Note: p is the probability of a 1 value, for each element.)

Putting all of that together, you can write a function to do this:

```
def sample(p):
    n = p.size
    a = np.random.uniform(0, 1, size=n)
    return (a < p).astype(int)
```

Comment: I understand what you did here, thank you! But imagine I add a seed in np.random for reproducibility. Every time I call sample with the same ```p``` it will return the same distribution. Also, the probabilities are not varying. Maybe I did not explained the question well, sorry!

Comment: @Janikas `Every time I call sample with the same p it will return the same distribution.` I thought that was the goal - that you wanted to be able reproduce it and get the same output. `Also, the probabilities are not varying.` I don't understand - why is the `p` variable present, if not to change the probability of getting 0 or 1?

Comment: Yes, but what I need is a sample that returns an array of size `n` where for an element in index 0 it used distribution p[0], for element in index 1 it used distribution p[1], and so on... The thing is that I need a different distribution every time I draw one choice between 0 and 1, but I can only call sample once because of the seed. Sorry if I'm being confusing and thank you for the help :)

Comment: If you use a random float in the range 0 to 1, and compare whether it's less than 0.3, that is mathematically the same thing as selecting 1 with probability 0.3 and 0 with probability 0.7. Even though it is selecting from the same uniform distribution each time, it is equivalent to selecting from a Bernoulli distribution with probability p for each row.

Comment: Is there any way to sample with replacement using this method?

Comment: @cgreen Not sure what you mean. This code *is* sampling with replacement. If it were sampling without replacement, that would imply that getting a 0 in the first position meant that you couldn't get a 0 in the second position. But the output of this example has repeated values.